# Launch external merge tool - command line svn

Tags: svn, merge, diff

I am trying to do a svn merge between 2 branches using command line svn 1.8.13 in mac. When there is a conflict, only 3 options are getting displayed.

> > local file obstruction, incoming file add upon merge Select: (r) mark resolved, (p) postpone, (q) quit resolution, (h) help:

But in 1.8.13 documentation, it is given that I will see some more options as below

> Select: (p) postpone, (df) diff-full, (e) edit,
>           (mc) mine-conflict, (tc) theirs-conflict,
>           (s) show all options:

I need to launch external merge tool (diffmerger) for conflict resolution. Since the options are not showing up I am pretty much stuck up here. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you choose `(s) show all options`, how the full list of available options looks like?

Comment: It says invalid option if I say "s"

Answer (score 1):

Define SVN_EDITOR environment variable

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.externaleditors.html